# run ponte in background and ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ssh, websocket, mqtt

I was trying to send realtime notification to android phones using ponte (http://www.eclipse.org/ponte/) and is working perfectly.

In order to start Ponte, I have to login in to my server (using SSH) and start ponte with the command " ponte -v "

The issue here is whenever I close the SSH console, the ponte get stopped and my devices will get disconnected.

Is there any way which I can keep ponte even after closing SSH console ?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can always start services with the nohup and & at the end so that it is not terminated when you exit the SSH session.

For your case:
    nohup ponte -v &

Answer (score 0):

Use the utility called screen. This create a new terminal session that you can disconnect from and will continue to run in the background. You can also reconnect later of needed.

Start screen with the following:

```
screen -S ponte
```

This starts a new session called `ponte`. You can then start ponte as normal, once started you can disconnect from the session by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> the pressing <kbd>d</kbd>

If needed you can reconnect by running

```
screen -r ponte
```

The manual for screen can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Screen can be used to run nearly any command line tool in the background